# Exploding an array for an email message

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am attempting to generate a weekly email to users of my site that lists locations that have added new information.  When someone adds information, a table receives two numbers, one for the state and the second for the county.  The first step of my cron job is to take the numbers and convert them to county, state format (Alameda, California for example).  At the end of each conversion I added a | to be used as a delimiter.  This part works perfectly.  Next I loop through each user to send this information via email but this part does not work.  What I end up with is the word array instead of my county, state format.  What am I missing?

This is the code that performs the 1st step, which works just fine:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$SID = $row['SID'];
$CID = $row['CID'];

$states = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM State WHERE ID = '$SID'");
while ($state = mysql_fetch_array($states)) {
    $statename = $state['Name'];
}

$countys = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM County WHERE ID = '$CID'");
while ($county = mysql_fetch_array($countys)) {
    $countyname = $county['Name'];
}

$locations = '<a href="http://hammerpins.net/display.php?state=' . $SID .' &county=' . $CID .'" >' . "$countyname, $statename ". '</a>' . "|";
$i = $i + 1;
}
```

This is the code that I am using to explode the array into the county, state format, which does not function properly.  Instead I get the word array.

```
$locals = explode("|", $locations);
```

$locals is used in the email message as the list of new information.  Please point me in the right direction.  Thanks

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I still must say it: This could be done in a much better way.  Holding a string full of elements and then exploding them could be done with an array.  Also, the data could be stored in the database much more efficiently for this too.

Comment: Thanks Flipper.  Actually, I did set it up as an array (which is the reason for the $i = 0 and the $i = $i + 1 lines.  As I couldn't come up with a way to mechanize the array into the email, I changed horses in the middle of the stream and went with the explode method, which based on all the comments appears to not be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what is the purpose of `$i`?

Second, I think you want to concatenate `$locations`:

```
// This overwrites the variable - this is what you are doing
// at the end $locations will be the one single last link
$locations = '<a href="ht

// This adds to / concatenates - giving you a long strong of many links
$locations .= '<a href="ht

        // ^ Note the period.
```

Third, explode does take a string and turns it into an array.

If you're making a long string, why would you want to explode it back into the parts you constructed it from?

I would suggest storing your states, countys, and constructed links in arrays. Then you can use the contents of those arrays at will to create your emails.

To look at what's in an array use [**print_r()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [**var_dump()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). You can loop over arrays with [**foreach()**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $SID = $row['SID'];
    $CID = $row['CID'];

    $states = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM State WHERE ID = '$SID'");
    while ($state = mysql_fetch_array($states)) {
        // There had better only be ONE statename per SID or you lose info!         
        $user_array[$i]['statename'] = $state['Name'];
    }

    $countys = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM County WHERE ID = '$CID'");
        while ($county = mysql_fetch_array($countys)) {
        // There had better only be ONE countyname per CID or you lose info!
        $user_array[$i]['countyname'] = $county['Name'];
    }


    $user_array[$i]['link'] = '<a href="http://hammerpins.net/display.php?state=' . $SID .' &county=' . $CID .'" >' . "{$user_array[$i]['countyname']}, {$user_array[$i]['statename']} ". '</a>';

    ++$i; // add one to i
}

// Show the arrays:
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The above gives you an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [statename] => CA
            [countyname] => San Bernardino
            [link] => <a href="blah...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [statename] => OR
            [countyname] => Multnomah
            [link] => <a href="yada...
        )

)
```

To use the array just do

```
foreach ($user_array as $single_user_item) {
    echo $single_user_item['link'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  As I mentioned above to Flipper, my first attempt at this was to use an array (which is why the $i=0 and $i=$i+1 lines) but couldn't quite figure out how to use the array in my email.  It may take me a while to fully understand what you are telling me, but if I have further questions, may I ask them?

Comment: @Poder - Using arrays is like using any other variable, so if you can use $locations in your email, you should be able to use an array too. There's [a whole section on arrays in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) . If you run into problems you should probably ask another question. Preferably with some dummy data setup. Arrays can be tricky at first, but once you grasp how to access and manipulate the elements of an array, they are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

explode will give you array

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

so when you use explode function, it will explode string in to array

in your case .. write

```
$locals = explode("|", $locations);
echo "<pre>";print_r($locals);echo "</pre>";
```

and you will have exact idea and it will solve your problem